# Lag during redirection from home page to a form in ionic angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiyfr.jpg)|[ionic form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiwuE.jpg)|[ionic issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f41T7.jpg)I have newly created an ionic angular app. I have created a form. I have a button in home page on click of it redirects to the form. But the issue is that there is a lag when the form is loaded.

There is no smooth transition from home page to the form. Could someone help on how to resolve this issue and achieve a smooth transition from the home page to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is not an issue as I had thought earlier but it is a default behavior of ionic routing. Looks like this is the default animation ionic provides when we route to some page. By setting [animated]="false" we can override the default behavior. Like this:

<ion-router-outlet id="main-content" [animated]="false">

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the transition to be over before updating the form view with the `ionViewDidEnter` lifecycle method. Don't delay the data loading tho, only template update or heavy JS computations would cause lag.

Without extra rendering the animation will be smooth. You can display placeholders in the meanwhile.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I tried ionViewDidEnter but it is not working. still the same issue. Actually there is no data in the form. it is an empty form with no data on load. I have attached the screen shots for home screen, form and also the transition from home page to form (Actual issue). for fraction of a second both the form home and form is visible. basically the transition is not smooth.

Comment: based on your inputs i tried as:

<-------ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      date: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      reasoning: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }----->

<-------<form
  [formGroup]="form"
  *ngIf="form">------>

But this did not work. Any inputs on this will be helpful!!

Comment: Is the lag present when the page is empty, without any form? You have the lag on every page, or this one only?

Comment: I found a solution which I have posted it. Thanks for the help!!